# Get one row from multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like

```
tableid  name  status uuid  date
1         a     none   1     2019-12-02
1         a     none   2     2019-12-02
1         a     done   4     2019-12-02
2         b     none   6     2019-12-02
2         b     done   7     2019-12-02
3         c     none   8     2019-12-02
```

if I had multiple rows for one table, I want to select the row of that table which is having status done. if any table doesn't have status like 'done' want to return 'none'.

```
tableid  name  status uuid  date
1         a     done   4     2019-12-02
2         b     done   7     2019-12-02
3         c     none   8     2019-12-02
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tableid ORDER BY status ASC) as RN,
           tableid,
           name,
           status,
           uuid,
           date
    FROM 
        SAMPLE
    )T
WHERE T.RN =1;
```

CHECK THIS : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/562f6b/4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below script if there are always none and done exists in the Status column-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0cd0a445dc1c915f32d81c641b422f43)

```
WITH your_table(tableid,name,status,uuid,date)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,'a','none',1,'2019-12-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'a','none',2,'2019-12-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'a','done',4,'2019-12-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'b','none',6,'2019-12-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'b','done',7,'2019-12-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'c','none',8,'2019-12-02'
)

SELECT tableid,name, MIN(status),MAX(uuid),MAX(date)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY tableid,name
ORDER BY tableid
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Postgres, I would recommend `DISTINCT ON`, which is generally more efficient than other approaches (and is also much simpler to write):

```
select distinct on(tableid) t.*
from mytable t
order by status, date desc
```

The second sorting criteria is there to consistently break the ties on status, if any (ie if there there are several records with status = none and no record with status = done, only, latest record will be picked)

Answer (score 0):

You want `distinct on` for this, but the correct formulation is:

```
select distinct on (tableid) t.*
from mytable t
order by tableid,
         (status = 'done') desc,
         (status = 'none') desc,
         date desc;
```

Your question is unclear on what you want if there are no nones or dones.

If there is at most one `done` and you want all `none`s if there is no `done`, then a different approach is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.status = 'done' or
      (t.status = 'none and
       not exists (select 1
                   from table t2
                   where t2.tableid = t.tableid and
                         t2.status = 'done'
                  )
      );
```